# Install WORKING iSCSI (BUT SCST) on Ubuntu 16.04 Kernel 4.8.0.53-generic

Tags: iscsi

Title says it all.  The "SCST Build Team" that has the BS, NON-WORKING repo crap posted, please do not offer that as an answer unless you can back it up with a video cap as I've now seen enough others post that it's BS too.

I can almost get it working.  Building 3.2.0 from source but the modules never load properly even with the correct make command, if I load manually I get the services started after manually loading modules, but I'm on hour 9 so now I need someone that has a CONFIRMED WORKING step by step to simply get the enterprise SCST iSCSI services running - I desperately need your assistance as does everyone since NONE of the MANY of these I've read actually work as written.

I mean my ancient kernel IX2 NAS somehow had SCST via lifeline apps working with a celeron and 256meg of friggin RAM, so I'm guessing a decade newer Ubuntu on a 8core i7 with 32gig RAM ought to be able to pull it off?  But, since it's not even in a regular repo, perhaps it just won't on this flavor of Linux or ?

EDIT:

Here's my DMESG, no errors so I'm out of ideas why nothing can see anything presented on the target:

```
[  907.082942] scst: Target template iscsi unregistered successfully
[  907.082946] iscsi-scst: Unregistered iSCSI transport: iSCSI-TCP
[  985.353804] iscsi-scst: iSCSI SCST Target - version 3.2.x
[  985.353807] iscsi-scst: Registered iSCSI transport: iSCSI-TCP
[  985.355329] scst: Target template iscsi registered successfully
[  985.355458] iscsi-scst: Read thread for pool ffff903e373cb400 started
[  985.355493] iscsi-scst: Read thread for pool ffff903e373cb400 started
[  985.355538] iscsi-scst: Write thread for pool ffff903e373cb400 started
[  985.357499] iscsi-scst: Write thread for pool ffff903e373cb400 started
```

My /etc/scst.conf that was working on SCST via NAS and even if I change to a newly created blank formatted volume file, same no-errors nothing presented:

```
HANDLER vdisk_fileio{
        DEVICE VMware {
                filename /mnt/pools/A/A0/iSCSI/VMware
                #filename /mnt/usb/iSCSI/iSCSI/VMware
                t10_dev_id LENOVO-b3fbe43e
                usn b3fbe43e
                nv_cache 1
        }
}

TARGET_DRIVER iscsi {
        iSNSServer 192.168.1.6
        enabled 1

        TARGET iqn.2012-07.com.lenovoemc:storage.ix2b.VMware {
                MaxRecvDataSegmentLength 8192
                MaxXmitDataSegmentLength 8192
                enabled 1
                LUN 0 VMware
        }
}
```

cat /proc/modules | grep scst

```
iscsi_scst 90112 3 - Live 0xffffffffc077d000 (OE)
scst_changer 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0761000 (OE)
scst_cdrom 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc075c000 (OE)
scst_tape 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0757000 (OE)
scst_raid 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0752000 (OE)
scst_processor 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc074d000 (OE)
scst_modisk 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc06b3000 (OE)
scst_user 40960 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0742000 (OE)
scst_vdisk 94208 0 - Live 0xffffffffc072a000 (OE)
scst_disk 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc066b000 (OE)
scst 446464 10 iscsi_scst,scst_changer,scst_cdrom,scst_tape,scst_raid,scst_processor,scst_modisk,scst_user,scst_vdisk,scst_disk, Live 0xffffffffc06bc000 (OE)
dlm 163840 1 scst, Live 0xffffffffc068a000
libcrc32c 16384 3 iscsi_scst,scst_vdisk,raid456, Live 0xffffffffc0114000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow so going to answer this one myself.  Blown away by this.

So I re-did the same build from 3.2.0 pre1 source (despite other docs, 3.1 refused to compile on my kernel so this was the 1st hurdle).

Now to the root cause of everything starting and NOT throwing a single error but 
also NOT presenting any iSCSI volumes -- I will return here to update further once I determine the WHY, but this whole silent failure is chalked up to one of the params in the config file that literally is a iscsi standard params right from the NAS.

NEW WORKING config file that the scstadmin in ubuntu regenerated:

```
# Automatically generated by SCST Configurator v3.2.0-pre1.


HANDLER vdisk_fileio {
        DEVICE VMware {
                filename /mnt/pools/A/A0/iSCSI/VMware
                read_only 1
        }
}

TARGET_DRIVER copy_manager {
        TARGET copy_manager_tgt {
                LUN 0 VMware {
                        read_only 1
                }
        }
}

TARGET_DRIVER iscsi {
        enabled 1

        TARGET iqn.2012-07.com.lenovoemc:storage.ix2b.VMware {
                enabled 1
                rel_tgt_id 1

                LUN 0 VMware {
                        read_only 1
                }
        }
}
```

Note that other than giving it read-only, there should theoretically be NO differences since it was re-generated with these exact commands:

```
scstadmin -open_dev VMware -handler vdisk_fileio -attributes filename=/mnt/pools/A/A0/iSCSI/VMware,read_only t10_dev_id=LENOVO-b3fbe43e usn=b3fbe43e nv_cache=1
scstadmin -add_target iqn.2012-07.com.lenovoemc:storage.ix2b.VMware -driver iscsi
scstadmin -add_lun 0 -driver iscsi -target iqn.2012-07.com.lenovoemc:storage.ix2b.VMware -device VMware
scstadmin -enable_target iqn.2012-07.com.lenovoemc:storage.ix2b.VMware -driver iscsi
scstadmin -set_drv_attr iscsi -attributes enabled=1
scstadmin -write_config /etc/scst.conf
```

So if anyone has an idea as to WHY this occurred it looks at first glance to be the addition of these:

```
t10_dev_id LENOVO-b3fbe43e
usn b3fbe43e
nv_cache 1
```

But I know the nv_cache is okay which leaves the first two which also despite being "attributes" didn't even pass through into the generated config file.

Anyway, the iSCSI volume just mounted right up so when I know more I'll update here so maybe it helps others.

Comment: Just to add, in the original config, apparently the newer versions (at some magic point) began REQUIRING DOUBLE QUOTES around the t10_dev_id which I did finally add back in to keep everything the same.  This basically confirmed that those stupid sudden double-quote requirement that did NOT exist when my old config file worked just fine with older kernels - is what cost me all that time pulling my hair out.  Every single other thing was correct.  Hopefully this helps someone  if you use that param be sure to now surround it in double quotes!!

Answer (score 0):

This script builds a package automatically and automates build of SCST SAN and multipath configuration on Ubuntu 16.04 (and also 14.04, 15.04 and 17.04 too).

https://sites.google.com/site/nandydandyoracle/scst/scst-package-build-and-install-ubuntu-17-04---14-04